# Complex search, search by district and council plus several other fields, Table structure help needed

Tags: mysql, sql, search, structure

I need to have a search functionality to search the db for items, but I'm not even sure how to save them in the DB properly.

I want to search by location, by district and council, the rest is more straight forward.

But each item can have more than one district and council, how do I save them in the database? Add another table that relates item Ids to districts and yet another table to relate to councils?

Something like

```
|id|item_id|district|
----------------------
|1 | 1     |dis_1   |
|2 | 1     |dis_2   |
|3 | 1     |dis_3   |
|4 | 1     |dis_4   |
```

And then a similar table for  councils?

The search would then match the district/council to the item_id.

Am I thinking properly?

Comment: Right now I only have one district field, the guy suddenly changed his mind and now wants multiple everything, haven't started, just want to know if this is the way it's supposed to be done

Comment: What is the relationship between Council and District?

Comment: Each district has multiple councils, but php logic will take care of that before inserting into the db.

Answer (score 0):

In general, when you have a many-to-many relationship you resolve that with a relationship table. So, in your example above, if you have an Item table and a District table, then you would create an ItemDistrict table that has just two columns: ItemId and DistrictId. This table does not need an id key of its own, as the combination of ItemId and DistrictId is the primary key.

If Councils are independent of Districts and an Item can have multiple councils, then you would have a second table ItemCouncil, with columns ItemId and CouncilId.

But if Districts are related to Councils and items are related to a subset of the District/Council combinations, you would need a table that related all three tables: ItemDistrictCouncil that had 3 columns: ItemId, DistrictId and CouncilId.

If the item is really only related to the District, and the District is related to the Councils, and so by inference the Item is related to any Council corresponding to the District, you would only need the ItemDistrict table. In that case you would join to the Councils through the Council's foreign key to the District.

Comment: Is it a bad idea to have districts as a string or varchar? or would it be better to have another table that associates districts to an int?

Comment: If the districts have a name that is unique, you can use that instead of a numeric ID. For best performance you want the relationship table to have the primary key or an indexed column, but if the tables are small it won't make much difference.

Comment: It will be unique.

I don't know if it's the best way though, each item can have 50 or more councils, having to insert 50 or more rows into the relationship table whever I insert an item sounds inefficient

Comment: Then you can use the string name.